# Emergency!! Need help uploading XAMPP website to web server

Tags: web, xampp

So I made a website using XAMPP (PHP website that has login functionality and connects to a database on Amazon Web Services) and I am using MySQL as the database language. 
To connect to my website, I just go to: http://localhost/users/index.php

[file hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVzYR.png)

So now, after the website has been made, (login works, and gets the specific information from the AWS database corresponding to that user, and I've done all the testing already) I then uploaded all the files inside the users folder into a directory (this directory corresponds to a subdomain ie. /triumph, which refers to triumph.liangbros.com) in the web server (using Netfirms as the host) but I get the following error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time
>   the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have
>   caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

The website can be seen at: triumph.liangbros.com

Can anybody please help me with this? I need the website live by year end and I am freaking out!! Please and thank you all!

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/overall/header.php'; 
?>

<?php
if (logged_in()) {
    //$username = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $session_user_id"))['username'];
    if($username === "admin"){
        //include 'includes/widgets/adminpanel.php';
    }
    else
        include 'includes/widgets/loggedin.php';
} else {
    include 'includes/widgets/login.php';
    echo "<h3>Please log in on the right hand side to view your investment summary.</h3>"; 
}
?>

<?php phpinfo(); ?>

<?php include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

connect.php

```
<?php
$connect_error = 'Sorry, we\'re expericing connection problems.';
mysql_connect('mydatabase.cgyrkrk8hpto.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com','myusername','mypassword') or die($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('invest') or die($connect_error);
?>
```

Comment: Wrong version of php? Missing modules? Could be a dozen things. Do you have access to the logs?  You may also want to consider continuous integration for your next project to avoid these last minute stresses.

Comment: So this is what I did:
1) logged into netfirms and created a subdomain called triumph.
2) using ftp, I uploaded all the files inside the users folder (as seen in the hierarchy) into the triumph folder that corresponds to that subdomain.
Do I have to add additional files, modules, etc? I'm not even sure where I can go from here. It is my first time using PHP for a website.

Comment: Keep it simple first: upload an index.php file that only displays phpinfo()..  Once you know for sure that is working..  Double check any connection strings..  Etc

Comment: Okay, I commented everything out and added phpinfo().  So what can i get out of this information? It can be seen at: http://triumph.liangbros.com/ also, if the EXACT files work in my localhost XAMPP, then shouldn't it work after uploading the files to the server?

Comment: I have put my index.php in the main post. 
This line is causing the error:
//$username = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $session_user_id"))['username'];

Comment: Php works.  Verify that you're using the same version in your development environment.  Compare your devenv phpinfo to prod environment.

Comment: Dev env: (PHP Version 5.6.15)
Prod env: (PHP Version 5.3.29)
So what can I do then? Do you think its a problem with the prod env using an older version of php?

Comment: Most likely.   I'd try installing 5.3 on your dev box just to confirm. Once confirmed you'll definitely have access to the server logs and you can comb through your code to rewrite pieces that aren't supported by 5.3

Comment: XAMPP came with its own version of PHP, and I looked here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/ and they don't offer a version with 5.3. Is there another way to install PHP 5.3 onto XAMPP?

Comment: There are other all in one windowz/php solutions besides xampp like http://www.easyphp.org/easyphp-devserver.php.   Do some more go ogling and good luck!

Comment: will try that, thanks for all your help and guidance!!

Comment: So i have changed all my code to reflect PHP Version 5.3.29. I have tested it using EasyPHP with PHP version 5.3.29 and it works. However, after uploading the files onto my web server, it is not connecting to my database which is hosted on Amazon Web Services, why is that? I have edited the post to include my connect.php which contains the code to connect to the database. Everytime, it runs "die($connect_error)". I displayed the errors and it shows:

Comment: Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mydatabase.cgyrkrk8hpto.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (111) in /hermes/bosnaweb03b/b2442/nf.liangbros/triumph/core/database/connect.php on line 6 Sorry, we're expericing connection problems.

Comment: I've added an answer.  After we get this straightened out,  let's rework your question and my answer to apply to a broader audience.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to Amazon aws mysql there are a couple things to check:

1. The Amazon account is set up to permit connections from your netfirms server.
2. The mysql server is bound to a public IP
3. The mysql user is configured to allow connections from your netfirms server